# Wordpress Post doesn't look like theme

Tags: wordpress

I downloaded a Theme called Neverland for my post area. I have two themes, one for the landing page (that I've created myself with html/css and javascript) and another for the blog. this neverland will be on the blog page. I also have a plugin for multiple themes.

The thing is that my blog page looks perfect, but once I open one blog post, it still uses the old layout. I want all my posts to have the look and feel of the new theme. How can I achieve this? thanks!

Comment: What is the plugin you're running that allows for multiple themes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all at a time you can't use two themes, Only one theme you can use it.
If you install and activate the neverland theme then only neverland theme's 
desing will be worked.
However I'm sending you a link here you can find the option to understand how to set up neverland theme. Here you can see the demo.xml file import part. You can import the demo file of neverland and see the single post
https://gt3themes.com/how-to-setup-neverland-free-personal-blog-wordpress-theme/